# How do I implement Laravel Analytics with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, charts, google-analytics, chart.js

Hi guys I am busy building a dashboard for my website and I want to add a chart that shows the sessions for the last 7 days. I have already setup my service account and I am receiving the data. Here is the output I receive:

```
[
    {"date":{"date":"2016-08-22 15:38:36.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"visitors":"0","pageViews":"0"},
    {"date":{"date":"2016-08-23 15:38:36.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"visitors":"0","pageViews":"0"},
    {"date":{"date":"2016-08-24 15:38:36.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"visitors":"0","pageViews":"0"},
    {"date":{"date":"2016-08-25 15:38:36.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"visitors":"0","pageViews":"0"},
    {"date":{"date":"2016-08-26 15:38:36.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"visitors":"0","pageViews":"0"}, 
    {"date":{"date":"2016-08-27 15:38:36.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"visitors":"0","pageViews":"0"},
    {"date":{"date":"2016-08-28 15:38:36.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"visitors":"0","pageViews":"0"}, 
    {"date":{"date":"2016-08-29 15:38:36.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"visitors":"1","pageViews":"5"}
]
```

My Controller function is like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use LaravelAnalytics;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        $analytics = LaravelAnalytics::getVisitorsAndPageViews(7);
        return view('admin.index')
            ->with(json_encode($analytics));
    }
}
```

I forgot to mention that I am using the Spatie\Laravel-Analytics library.
My Javascript looks like this to render a demo chart.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("sessions");
var sessions = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Sessions Last 7 Days',
            data: [4,8, 19, 3, 5, 4, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(52, 73, 94,0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(52, 73, 94,1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

My question is how do I get the data received from json to display in the chart?

Answer (score 0):

if you already have a json object/file you can get the data with json.parse(json var) , it will return you the data

Answer (score 0):

You take 7 from your controller but the output is 8, check that also. And In your JS

```
var myData = [
   @foreach($analytics as $analis)
      {{ $analis->visitors }}, //remeber to put comma (,) at end for array
   @endforeach
]

data: {
    datasets: [{
        data: myData,
    }]
},
```